# Downwards square bracket with text going through middle

Tags: html, css

How do I create a square bracket facing down with text in the middle?

I've found ways of creating a straight line through text, but I can't find any way to have the lines either side facing down.

[image: Image example - made in photoshop]

This is just the line but I want the brackets on the sides.

```css
div {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 600;
}
div:before,
div:after {
 background-color: #000;
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 height: 4px;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 50%;
}
div:before {
 right: 0.5em;
 margin-left: -50%;
}
div:after {
 left: 0.5em;
 margin-right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Text1</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain with what you have done to get this output? because we have no time to make new code to fulfill you requirements.

Comment: do what you don't consider border-top instead of bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
     height: 40px;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
span{
 background-color: #fff;
       position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    padding: 0px 14px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>text</span></div>
```